# Nintendo DS Lite glitchy screen

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-ds, hardware

I have loved my DS and taken good care of it for 5 years. Nintendo consoles are build to last, that's for sure. But a few minutes ago I was playing Animal Crossing: Wild World on a flashcard [trying to be very specific so I might be able to get help]. The screen started getting all scrambled and a bunch of white lines filled the screen. It got worse when I moved the top screen back and forth. Please, is there anything I can do to fix it? It holds many good memories and I am very sentimental about it. In case you are wondering, it does this for any other game including the main menu.

Comment: Just to clarify - the glitches also happen WITHOUT the flashcard in the DS?

Comment: Yes, it happens on the boot screen as well.

Comment: There's a little flat cable that wraps around the hinge to connect the top screen.  It could be a loose cable (and then you just need to reseat it), or the cable itself could be getting worn in a specific spot.  Only way to find out is to open it up, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears an issue that a [few](http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/7896) [people](http://www.nintendolife.com/forums/ds/ds_top_screen_keeps_flickering) have experienced, including myself.

It's apparently due to a cable connection coming loose, which is why it gets worse when you move the hinge.

When this happened to me, it progressed to a point where the screen hinge ended up snapping completely, so I'd take this as an early warning and find someone who can repair it before the problem gets worse. You could always attempt it yourself if you're feeling brave - there seem to be some videos on YouTube for it, but I can't vouch for their accuracy.

Depending on your location, you may be able to send it to Nintendo themselves for repair:

http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/assets/region_select.jsp

Comment: I think Nintendo has discontinued support for the original DS/DS Lite. EDIT: Never mind, they still support sending it in for repairs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SamS Glad to hear! Good luck getting it fixed.